# React Native - Expo ¿cómo quitar el header blanco superior?

Tags: react-native, programación-móvil, expo

Quiero quitar el header blanco, el que dice "< Scanner"
Pero no logro hacerlo.

Ya he intentado lo siguiente:

[image: LoginScreen.navigationOptions = { header: 'null', headerMode: 'screen', };]

Probé junto, separado, de a solo una, pero no funciona, el header sigue ahí.
Alguna idea de como quitarlo ?

Comment: Es mi primera pregunta jaja y veo que no salió el código. 
Pasaré aqui:

LoginScreen.navigationOptions = {
    header: 'null',
    headerMode: 'screen',
};

Probé tal cual lo ven y también uno a la vez, pero no funcionó de ninguna forma.

Comment: El código va en la pregunta, por favor lee [ask]